# How to identify who is the Site Collection Administrators without being one?

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, sharepoint-administration

Can anyone tell me how to find out who is the Site Collection Administrators of a SharePoint without being a Site Collection Administrators of this SharePoint? 
This can be really useful for continuity reasons. 
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Why not just contact IT and ask them?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SharePoint Central Administration, you can navigate to Application Management-> Change site collection administrators to find out.

Or you can use script to get the list of Site Collection Administrator. For the script of REST API and JQuery, you can check the similar post: [Sharepoint 2013 - List of Site Collection Administrator (JavaScript)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200254/sharepoint-2013-list-of-site-collection-administrator-javascript)